# How to extract data from a secure website like bloomberg

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, bloomberg, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape item on this url:

```
"https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05-30/tesla-dealt-another-blow-as-barclays-sees-it-as-niche-carmaker"
```

I wanted to get the title and date publish only, 
any sample code that you can give to me even splash etc

so far what I tried is this

```
 def parse(self, response):
   yield scrapy.Request('https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05-30/tesla-dealt-another-blow-as-barclays-sees-it-as-niche-carmaker -H x-crawlera-use-https:1',
        headers={'X-Crawlera-Session': create,
        'X-Crawlera-Timeout': 40000,
        'X-Crawlera-Max-Retries': 5,
        'X-Crawlera-Cookies': disable,
        'X-Crawlera-Session': self.session_id
        },
        callback=self.parse_sub,
        )

 def parse_sub(self, response):
    response.xpath("//h1[@class = 'lede-text-v2__hed']").extract_first()
    response.xpath("//meta[@property = 'og:title']/@content").extract_first()
    response.xpath("//time[@class = 'article-timestamp']/@datetime").extract_first()
   print(response.text)
```

I am also using crawlera, but it keep detecting me as a robot

Comment: Would you consider accepting an answer using only _Selenium_?

Comment: yes Iwill @DebanjanB

Comment: So you want to extract **Tesla Dealt Another Blow When Barclays Calls It a ‘Niche Carmaker’** and **May 30, 2019, 5:26 PM GMT+5:30 Updated on May 30, 2019, 7:21 PM GMT+5:30** both ... rit?

Comment: Yes you are right @DebanjanB

Comment: @DebanjanB I just only need the May 30, 2019, 5:26 PM GMT+5:30 "not updated on" thank you

Comment: try the python library, crawling a website with http requests will not work https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python. That is what the apis are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) to extract the *title* i.e. **Tesla Dealt Another Blow When Barclays Calls It a ‘Niche Carmaker’** and the *publishing date* i.e. **May 30, 2019, 5:26 PM GMT+5:30** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05-30/tesla-dealt-another-blow-as-barclays-sees-it-as-niche-carmaker')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='markets']//following:: h1[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='markets']//following:: h1[1]//following::div[@class='lede-text-v2__times']/time[@itemprop='datePublished']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Tesla Dealt Another Blow When Barclays Calls It a ‘Niche Carmaker’
  May 30, 2019, 5:26 PM GMT+5:30
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I am trying your code but I am having error on 'WebDriverWait' is not defined

Comment: Hi @debanjanB still having "error name 'driver' is not defined" I don't know why

Comment: @ChristianRead Checkout the answer update and let me know the status

Comment: Hi @debanjanB, I am actually trying it on scrapy shell, I don't know if it will work there. I tried to put your code inside "def parse(self, response):" no print response. and If I will not put it inside I am having error.

Comment: @ChristianRead I don't think you can execute the code block on scrapy shell. It's pure _Selenium_ with _Python_

Comment: Where can I test your code? Sorry I am really new at selenium

Comment: Any Python shell once you install the Selenium packages.

Comment: I don't know why I am getting this error "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH." I added all the import you had suggested

Comment: After trying working on your code I made it run now, Thank you @debanjanB .